# Inherited constructor cannot be used to copy object

Tags: c++, inheritance, copy-constructor

This program does not compile:

```
template <class T>
struct Base {
    Base();

    template <class U>
    Base(const Base<U>&);
};


template <class T>
struct Doh : Base<T> {
    using Base<T>::Base;
};


template <class T>
struct Derp : Base<T> {
    using Base<T>::Base;
};


Doh<void> x = Derp<void>();
```

The error message says `inherited constructor cannot be used to copy object`. [Live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/MoWzE4).

But when we change the last line to this, it compiles.

```
Doh<void> doh;
Doh<void> x1 = doh;
Doh<void> x2 = Derp<void*>();
Doh<void> x3(Derp<void>());
```

In these three cases the inherited constructor can be used. Why?

Comment: How underhanded! I got your sample on Compiler Explorer compiling: [**Fixed Demo on Compiler Explorer**](https://godbolt.org/z/T5KEfd). After fiddling around for a while I reduced the error to single complaint about the deleted copy constructor of `Doh<void>`. `Doh` not `Derk`??? It's the initialization which seems to cause an intermediate step - something like `Doh<void> x = Doh<void>(Derk<void>());`... But, I'm not able to explain this in detail. It's just that I faced similar issues sometimes in VS2013 (and always believed it's just because VS2013 is simply too aged.) ;-)

Comment: Notice that `template <class U> Base(const Base<U>&)` is NOT a copy constructor, and `Base(const Base<T>&)` would still be generated.

Comment: @Jarod42: You are right. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/sn1aba).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because that is how it is prescribed to work.

> [[over.match.funcs/9]](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.funcs#general-9.sentence-2) A constructor inherited from class type C ([class.inhctor.init]) that has a first parameter of type “reference to cv1 P” (including such a constructor instantiated from a template) is excluded from the set of candidate functions when constructing an object of type cv2 D if the argument list has exactly one argument and C is [reference-related](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.ref#def:reference-related) to P and P is
> reference-related to D.

Here `D = Doh<void>`, `C = Base<void>` and the constructor of interest is the constructor with `U = void` which make `P = Base<void>`. That constructor is not available, and no other one fits.

```
Doh<void> x1 = doh;
```

This is OK because it uses the defaulted copy constructor of `Doh<void>`.

```
Doh<void> x2 = Derp<void*>();
```

This is OK because `Base<void*>` is not reference-related to `Doh<void>`.

The "point" of this language is that they want to exclude things that look like copy/move constructors. A `Base` template constructor could otherwise be greedy and be a better match than a provided or defaulted `Derived` copy/move constructor which would potentially be surprising.

---

Updated:

```
Doh<void> x3(Derp<void>());
```

This does not declare and initialize a `Doh<void>`. It declares a function `x3` returning a `Doh<void>` and taking a single argument which is a function which takes no arguments and returns `Derp<void>`. It is a typical example of the "most vexing parse".

To declare and initialize a `Doh<void>`, you can use braces:

```
Doh<void> x3{Derp<void>()};
```

This fails to compile as expected.